# Should you show preference to a Jew/ Jewish establishment?

Tags: halacha, gentiles, am-yisrael-jewish-nation, business

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Purchasing from a Jew](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6271/purchasing-from-a-jew)

If you have the opportunity to do business or make purchases with either a non-Jew or a Jew equally is there any reason to prefer the Jew over the non-Jew? For example I can buy a loaf of bread at Yanky's kosher supermarket or at the non-Jewish supermarket. The price is the same. Is there any reason to shop at Yanky's over the other?

Comment: @GershonGold I think you are right, I didn't see that before.

Comment: While a dup, this formulation seems more "accessible" and may be found more easily via search.  Closing makes sense but we should not delete.  (leaving this note for a future custodian; I don't think we'd delete now.)