# Is there really no problem with paying non-Jewish employees less than Jewish employees?

Tags: mussar-ethics, business

The Times of Israel has a [feature on B&H](http://www.timesofisrael.com/nyc-electronics-store-earns-gelt-with-orthodox-business-model/?utm_source=dlvr.it&utm_medium=twitter), the Satmar owned camera store.  B&H has been successfully sued several times for discriminating against non-Jewish employees, including for paying them less than Jewish employees, and blocking them from management positions.  In the article, Rabbi Daniel Lapin, who is an Orthodox rabbi and an author of several Jewish business books is quoted in the article as saying:

> Lapin maintains that none of the aforementioned allegations undermine B&H’s integrity. “Where in the Torah does it say that you have to pay all employees the same rate? Where in the Torah is equality depicted as a virtue? The answer is nowhere at all.” The company’s business model, according to Lapin, adheres to God’s plan insofar as it’s described in, “His book.”
>
> “The notion that there’s a moral flaw in people who, because they don’t pay all their employees the same — I’m not sure I see the basis for that in morality. It may not be fair, it may not be legal, those are not my areas. But to say that there is a clash with Jewish values simply would not be true,” said Lapin.

Is Lapin's view correct? **Excluding [*dina d'malchuta*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dina_d%27malkhuta_dina) issues**, is it correct that there is no moral problem in Judaism with workplace discrimination?  If so, what sources support this claim?

Comment: If someone agreed to work for a certain price, what's wrong with that? Some people negotiate better than others.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17318/759

Comment: @DoubleAA B&H may be negotiating harder with non-Jewish employees, while more quickly acceding to the demands of Jewish employees.  Again, I don't know if that's against halacha or "Jewish values" (though it sounds like marat ayin to me), but it certainly feels wrong.

Comment: I don't know what feels wrong about it. It's not like they're forcing anyone to do anything. You've never asked a friend to have their boss look at your resume? Business is all about who you know.

Comment: Which issur could one possibly violate?

Comment: The workplace discrimination is a real thing and it is wrong. God, who is all good, cannot demand bad things.

Comment: ועשית הישר והטוב. Also if it draws negative attention to Jews, you should probably avoid it.

Comment: Might there be a problem of eivah, similar to giving Goyim charity?

Comment: Not a good look for a Jewish company.

Answer (score 1):

B"H

You're asking us to prove a negative.

One has to know every halacha in the torah thoroughly to say for certain "no", which is not often feasible.

However, I'm not aware of any halacha that suggests that one has to pay all of one's employees the same rate for the same task.

If there would be an issue, one may suggest that it's related to the prohibition it [Onnat Maamon](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.koltorah.org/halachah/an-in-depth-analysis-of-onaat-mamon-part-1-by-leead-staller%3Fformat=amp), which means to charge more than market value for certain goods, or buy them for less than market value, with several exceptions.

However, according to all of the sources I can find on the matter (see link above), this only applies to actual **goods**, moveable items and land. If one were to find a source that it also applies to **services**, then one may argue that by paying some employees less than others for the same exact job, then either they were overpaying one or underpaying the other, which may be in violation of price fraud.

Nevertheless, as mentioned, the sources I was able to find limit Onnat Maamon to goods only:

fundamentally, when one overcharges or underpays a fellow member of Bnei Yisrael, he transgresses the Lav of Ona’ah, whether it is a transaction of **movable goods** or **real estate**.

In addition, I'm not aware of the implications of Onnat Mamon in regards to non Jews, according to the sources it only applies to Jews.

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first answer. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Onaat Mammon can apply to employment in some circumstances... CM 227:36

Answer (score 1):

> הוּא הָיָה אוֹמֵר, כָּל שֶׁרוּחַ הַבְּרִיּוֹת נוֹחָה הֵימֶנּוּ, רוּחַ הַמָּקוֹם נוֹחָה הֵימֶנּוּ. וְכָל שֶׁאֵין רוּחַ הַבְּרִיּוֹת נוֹחָה הֵימֶנּוּ, אֵין רוּחַ הַמָּקוֹם נוֹחָה הֵימֶנּוּ.‏

> He [Rabbi Chanina ben Dosa] used to say: One who is pleasing to his fellow men is pleasing also to God; and one who is not pleasing to his fellow men is also displeasing to God.

-- [Avot 3:10](https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.3.10), with translation from [*The Hirsch Pirkei Avos*](https://www.feldheim.com/chapters-of-the-fathers-1-1), where it's designated 3:13

> The designation of מקום for God implies the universal relationship of God to the world. ... The designation for human beings, which embraces all of mankind, regardless of individual differences, is בריות, literally "creations." ... Just as all men, being the creatures of God, enjoy the same relationship to the One Who is their sole Creator and are united through Him, so, too, despite all the many ways in which individuals differ from one another, people should draw close to one another; ... Yet there is a way of living together that all of us can accept, so that no one becomes unpleasant and burdensome, hostile or unkind to the other, but instead each of us finds pleasure in the company of the other and feels drawn to him. ... If you are really wiser, better, and nobler than others, then strive also to be more pleasant and amiable, so that people will like to be near you and absorb into their own personalities, some of your wisdom, goodness, and moral nobility.

-- Commentary from *The Hirsch Pirkei Avos*, ibid.

In this mishna, we learn the basic Jewish moral value of "acting like a [mensch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mensch)" - behaving toward all people with whom one interacts in a way that they find pleasing. It seems to me that behavior toward employees that they consider unfair would naturally be in tension with this value, as people pretty universally prefer and expect fairness from the people they interact with.

To be sure:

- Different people have different understandings of what is fair.
- Particularly in the complex realm of human resources practices, it's impossible to please everyone, or indeed to behave in a way that everyone considers "fair."
- In any human interaction, there are other Jewish values in play that could be in tension with that of pleasing all people. This mishna is certainly not presenting an absolute demand that our every action must be the one that people around us prefer.
- The specific details of the HR environment at B&H and the merits of the workers' complaints are not fully available to us, and this question is *not* asking us to adjudicate whether B&H executed an appropriate balancing of all of the relevant Jewish values in its HR behaviors.

What this question does ask is whether one can flatly state, as Rabbi Lapin seems to in the article (though newspaper quotations frequently leave context and nuance on the cutting-room floor) that "there is no moral problem in Judaism with workplace discrimination." It seems to me that, as it is a pattern of behavior that naturally causes people to be displeased, workplace discrimination clearly presents a moral problem within Judaism. Appropriate solutions to that problem will vary.

Comment: Presented as an extension of the merit of Z'kenti Morati Sarah bat Hillel, who recently passed away, who told me about how she grew up saying Pirkei Avot on Shabbat afternoons, and who was a big believer in fairness.

Comment: יהי זכרה ברוך - sounds like she was a pretty cool gal

Comment: The passage from Pirkei Avot is compelling, but it doesn't answer the question posted. Your answer applies to manage the reputation of the Jewish community when people become aware of the discrimination and are displeased by it. Your answer does not address the behavior. The question remains, - is there no moral problem in Judaism with workplace discrimination? "Don't do this because it upsets people" is much different that "Don't do this because it is against Jewish values."

Comment: @PaulWalker the point of this mishna, which I believe is a profound and foundational one, is that upsetting people *is* against Jewish values, essentially, not as a matter of PR.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Rabbi Lapin said according to the Torah B&H did nothing wrong, but actually follows God's plan. Your answer doesn't address the OP's question. Or do you mean, "True, B&H's discrimination doesn't violate Torah or Jewish values, but in the spirit of this Avos, we don't do such things because it upsets the community we live in." Is that what you're saying or am I reading into it too much?

Comment: @PaulWalker I may need to clarify how I think this principle applies, as you're getting it differently from how I intend. The problem isn't that it looks bad to the surrounding community; it's that the workers felt cheated. By behaving in a way that the workers felt was unfair, the company displeased them, thus putting its behavior in tension with the value expressed in this mishna. "God is not happy with you" describes tension with a core Jewish value, not a PR misstep.

Answer (score 0):

What Rabbi Lapin said is shocking to me, as a Noahide.

I think Rabbi Lapin is wrong.

In the Noahide Laws, we are prohibited from stealing. Cheating an employee is a form of theft. This company hired people under the workplace laws of the USA. They may not discriminate against non-Jews and women in promotions and raises. But they did, several times.  The wages and promotions that those people rightfully earned were 'stolen' by the company and given to others who had not earned them.

In Aaron Lichtenstein's book , "The Seven Laws of Noah", he discusses views of the Hinnuch, Aaron HaLevi of Barcelona, in his compendium of the six hundred thirteen commandments, Negative 247 ("...against cheating"),

> "This is directed at the non-payment of a worker's salary, the non-payment of a loan, and the non-return of a borrowed object. The common features here are: (a) that the item under dispute reaches the hands of the cheat legally, (b) that the wrongful act is essentially one of omission instead of commission. Even so, Noahide law prohibits such an act, for in spirit it constitutes theft."

And he also references Maimonides, Code, "Laws on Kings" 9:9, "A Noahite is punishable for stealing...for withholding a worker's pay..."

Withholding earned promotions and earned raises, for no other reason than to give it to one that has not earned it, is withholding a worker's pay, and is theft.

Perhaps Judaism has a different regard for non-Jews and women in business, and maybe that works in the land of Israel, but the employer agreed to follow these laws when he setup the business in America. The fact that they are Jewish-owned should make them MORE willing to be exacting on employees' wages.

Consider a Jew working for a Gentile. Jews need a lot of time off. Observant Jews have a lot of restrictions and request a lot of accommodations. If a Gentile were paid more than a Jew, there are many instances where that could be justified. They can count on the Gentile when needed most. But we don't do that, because it is hateful and distasteful to Gentiles in America, so we passed laws against such discriminatory practices.

What would Hillel say? Here's a distilled version by [Aish.com](https://aish.com/judaisms-golden-rule/)...

> The Talmud tells the story of a gentile who came to Shammai requesting a quickie McConversion to Judaism. He asked to be taught the entire Torah while standing on one foot. Shammai had no patience for the ridiculous and disrespectful request and chased him out of the study hall.
>
> Undaunted, the fellow then proceeded to visit Shammai's colleague, Hillel with the same request. Hillel instructed him, "Whatever is hateful and distasteful to you, do not do to your fellow man. This is the entire Torah, the rest is commentary. Go learn."

Comment: Is this an answer to the original question or a rant?

Comment: MY is a bit different from other sites you might be used to. Answers are meant to answer the question at hand. They are not meant for discussions. As such it is always possible your answer gets deleted if the community decides it is not fit for the format of the site

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I've made edits to more clearly focus the answer to the question.

Comment: You are right that not paying a salry is cheating. This employer did pay their salries. They wanted a bigger salsry is not stealing.

There is opinions including that of prominent dayaonim in my town, that if there are statury laws defining salaries, then these are binding end enforcable. But there is no source from the torah itself for such a law.

Comment: The parts of this answer that rely on a requirement to follow local law and custom aren't responsive to the question, which specifies "excluding [dina d'malchuta](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dina_d%27malkhuta_dina) issues." The last part, invoking Hillel, is not strictly Halachic, but strikes me as very persuasive, in terms of basic Jewish morality, which is what the question asks for.

Comment: Stealing is of course wrong but you haven't proven there to be any theft. Regardless of your personal opinion on the matter this doesn't answer the question

Comment: @PaulWalker thanks for contributing. I think that you neglect to demonstrate that halakhah treats wage disparity as theft - which is (to my understanding) your main thesis. As for the laws of the land, the OP explicitly expressed a desire to preclude it from the discussion. As for Hillel's statement, you do not demonstrate that any and all discrepant payment practices would be deemed hateful/distasteful to your fellow man. It seems to me that halakhah on this particular topic reflects something closer to traditional free market values (which in recent decades US law has been straying from).

Comment: You might find these short articles on Mises.org to be of interest: [Freedom and Discrimination](https://mises.org/library/freedom-and-discrimination) and [Differences Don't Necessarily Equal Discrimination](https://mises.org/library/differences-dont-necessarily-equal-discrimination)

Comment: @Deuteronomy Not wage disparity. That would simply be underpaying someone, which was alluded to in the article - 'they should negotiate better.' What is this discrimination that B&H did, if not theft? If the employees who sued were not entitled to those raises and promotions, there would be no reason for the lawsuit. B&H withheld what was due them. This was proven. In this case, the 'law of the land' exposed the theft.

Comment: @PaulWalker As long as it was agreed upon, paying two different people doing the same job different wages is not inherently theft, no matter how many times you simply say that it is. You are not proving your case, you are merely asserting naked conclusions. In none of the cases was it argued that agreed upon wages were withheld. Nothing is "proven" or "exposed" other than that BH settled out of court because it thought it may be found liable of anti-discrimination laws (not theft). I reiterate the halakhah on this issue is closer to free-market practice. That does not inherently make it theft

Comment: @Deuteronomy the question asks for morals, not Halacha.

Comment: @IsaacMoses that is true, R. Lapin spoke of morals/Jewish-values. However it is here being alleged that a particular tort (theft), with its own elements in halakhah has been violated. This is simply not being demonstrated. Where demonstrated, surely a moral infraction as defined by Jewish values, would go in hand with it.

Comment: @Deuteronomy There are 2 issues here. 1 - the discrimination for paying Jewish males more than women or Gentiles for doing the same job. 2 - the company withheld promotions and raises from Gentiles and women. I say that if these promotions and raises were rightfully earned and would have been paid had they been Jewish males, then this is theft.

Comment: You are simply restating your prior claims without demonstrating them. Stating your claim again does not make them correct.  1) Was there any contractually agreed upon duty violated? (e.g. "if you meet this quota, you will earn a raise to be applied in the next quarter") 2) Was there any contractual agreement to "earn" promotions/raises? ("if you perform x actions in such and such a fashion, you will earn y promotion or z raise in such dollar amount") If the answer is no - then the two parties (employer/employee) are simply doing what was mutually agreed upon by them.

Comment: Indeed, the contrary may be argued to be theft. To apply state coercion to the employer to pay a particular employee in excess of their mutually agreed upon duties to each other may itself constitute theft.

Comment: @Deuteronomy I agree that "theft" per se is not demonstrated here. As I indicated above, I find that last two paragraphs in particular persuasive. If a business chose to systematically pay Jewish employees less than non-Jewish employees, I would find that objectionable. Therefore, it seems to me that the core Jewish value expressed by Hillel is one that employers should indeed take into account before choosing to systematically pay non-Jewish employees less than Jewish employees.

Comment: @IsaacMoses I think of it slightly differently. If there was a reasonable expectation that all employees would be equally eligible for a higher salary - then it may be argued that the reasonable expectation created a duty which the employer violated. If there was no such reasonable expectation, then no duty was created and the employee is not owed anything beyond what was contractually agreed upon. In this scenario, setting aside the actual discrimination laws, the laws reflect a culture wherein there is such an expectation - in which case a duty *may* have been violated.

Comment: The value of Hillel (for which we're setting aside the obvious halakhic aspect of it being applicable solely between Jews), is not a hard rule unambiguosly applied. Say a group of ten kids come along to shovel an old man's home out in return for cash. Of the ten, a handful are actually his grandchildren. He pays all of the kids and immediately afterwards invites just his grandchildren in for hot cocoa and treats. Was the grandfather acting morally defectively according to Hillel's dictum?

Comment: I don't think the answer to that is clearly in the affirmative. Nor is it here. And if it ought be applied, then I think that should be argued out and shown, rather than simply stated... also, we're probably abusing the comments section by this point lol.