# Is there a problem with gender pay discrimination

Tags: halacha, women, choshen-mishpat-civil-law, mussar-ethics, contemporary-halacha

Inspired by [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/52809/33665) I am curious if there is any issue in Halacha or anything else with paying (Jewish) women less than (Jewish) men or vice versa? Since there is a mitzvah to do business with fellow Jews, I wonder if this type of discrimination among Jews presents any problem (excluding Dina D’malchuta Dina, assuming this is in a place where pay discrimination is legal).

Comment: The Torah itself says a woman’s ערך is less than a man’s

Comment: @CuriousYid I'm obviously not suggesting that we change the Torah but that was presumably talking to when important jobs required physical strength, not sure that would hold true with most modern day jobs . .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

B"H

There is no halacha saying that an employer is obligated to pay all of one's employees the same rate for different tasks, or even for the same task.

There is a related halachic concept known as Onaat Maamon - price fraud - although according to the sources I was able to find, this only applies to moveable goods or real estate, I'm not able to find any sources that suggest it refers to overpaying or underpaying one for a service (as opposed to goods).

This is just in general, I'm not aware of any source that, in addition, would make a distinction between different types of employees, for example different genders.

[Source](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.koltorah.org/halachah/an-in-depth-analysis-of-onaat-mamon-part-1-by-leead-staller%3Fformat=amp):

fundamentally, when one overcharges or underpays a fellow member of Bnei Yisrael, he transgresses the Lav of Ona’ah, whether it is a transaction of **movable goods** or **real estate**

Comment: @Kirk if the answer is "no, there is no halacha suggesting that" what else should be added to this answer?