# Doing Business with a Jew

Tags: halacha, business, transactions

The Gemorah in Bava Metzia 71a teaches that one must give preference to a Jew when offering out loans even when it will cause a loss to the lender since he won't be able to charge interest.

Practically today how does gemorah effect the halacha? Must I buy kosher brands? Must I hire a Jew who is less qualified than a non-jew?

Comment: Interesting question but (1) can you clarify what "buying kosher brands" mean? in opposition to what? non-kosher products? and (2) best to limit yourself to one question per question and be specific with your questions (how does gemorah effect halacha is very broad - can you specify exactly what you are looking for?)

Comment: The mitzvah of lending money without interest to a Jew is rather specific in scope

Comment: In general, if you have the choice of doing business with a Jew and a non-Jew, it would be better to chose the Jew. If the merchandise, service or price of the non-Jew is better, then you are free to chose. I believe we have a question on this but need to look for it

Comment: related: [Purchasing from a Jew](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6271/11501)

Comment: @mbloch - does "business ethics" hopefully get added to the other three items on your list? As far as providing business services for real estate owners is concerned, I could think of 20 or 30 Gentile owners I prefer to work for than Jewish ones, especially the "most observant" ones that should be good examples, but instead treat their vendors, supers, and tenants, like...well, poorly, not doing repairs until forced to, and chiseling every nickel they can when getting service for their buildings. After dealing with over 20, I can count on 2 fingers the number of them I answer the phone for.

Comment: Can anyone out there please tell me why over 90 percent of the real estate owners that I try and give extra respect for, since they appear to be the "10 percent righteous holding up the world", turn out to be the absolute worst people to deal with, business-wise??